# Corrupted Collection Name and Properites Name c# Mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

Since we have migrated to Mongo.Core c# driver version 2.7.0 and MongoDB 4.0 we have started getting this issue, the name of the collections/properties is getting corrupted e.g EventLogItems is becoming EtentLngAtems 
We are also seeing similar issues with name of the properties, this was very few initially but we are seeing a lot of these now. 
Attached is the list of collections with name corrupted.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards, 
Gourav Sinha

[Corruption of Collection name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpkNo.png)

Comment: You mention a 'lot of issues' but your post doesn't actually contain a question. StackOverflw works best with specific questions. Have a look here for guidance on asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I was finally able to solve the issue by rolling back to MongoDb 3.6 hope this is helpful to others.